# How to fetch record from three table in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have four tables

`jobposts`:

```
id | user_id | cat_id | job_title

1  |   1     |   1    | job 1
2  |   1     |   2    | job 2
3  |   2     |   3    | job 3
4  |   1     |   3    | job 4
```

`categorymasters`:

```
id | category_name

1  |   cat1 
2  |   cat2  
3  |   cat3  
4  |   cat4
```

`lastsubcategoryselectedbycompanies`:

```
id | jobposts_id | lastsubcategorymasters_id

1  |   1     |   1 
2  |   1     |   2 
3  |   2     |   3  
4  |   1     |   3
```

`lastsubcategorymasters`:

```
id | LastSubCategoryName

1  |   lastsubcat1  
2  |   lastsubcat2  
3  |   lastsubcat3  
4  |   lastsubcat4
```

- `jobposts` have unique rows.
- `lastsubcategoryselectedbycompanies` is a mapping of `jobposts` and  `lastsubcategorymasters`.

Now assume some user is logged in with their credentials (EX: take `user_id` 1 in `jobposts`). Now I need to show `LastSubCategoryName` in a comma separated list from the `lastsubcategorymasters` table, grouped by the `jobposts`, `lastsubcategoryselectedbycompanies` and `lastsubcategorymasters` tables.

`allpostedjob.blade.php` is:

```
@foreach($jobposteddetails as $jobposteddetail)
    <tr>
     <td>{{ $jobposteddetail->job_title }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

cotroller is:

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $jobposteddetails = jobpost::with('categorymaster')->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
        return view('jobprovider.allpostedjob', compact('user','jobposteddetails'));
    }
```

`jobpost.php` model is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class jobpost extends Model
{
    function categorymaster()
     {
          return $this->belongsTo(categorymaster::class, 'cat_id');
     }
}
```

It is working proper.

But I also need to show `LastSubCategoryName` grouped by the tables `jobposts`, `lastsubcategoryselectedbycompanies` and `lastsubcategorymasters`.

```
function lastsubcategory()
     {
          return $this->belongsTo(lastsubcategoryselectedbycompanies::class);
     }
```

It is not working. How can I fetch my result?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very skilled at applying complex queries with eloquent, I prefer to use DB query builder with the join method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries